# How to encode text in pango-markup language?

Tags: gstreamer, glib, subtitle, pango

I am writing a subtitle parser gstreamer plugin. I need to encode parser subtitle text in pango-markup language as the gstreamer text-overlay supports it.

I know how to decode pango-markup text to normal text from [this link](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#PangoAttrList).

But I am not able to find a standard utility library which can encode normal string to pango-markup string.

Is there a standard encoder library for pango-markup? Or should I implement the encoder myself?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are expecting from "encoding to pango-markup string." Pango markup is just XML-escaped text, with optional formatting markup elements in it.

That is, [`g_markup_escape_text()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Simple-XML-Subset-Parser.html#g-markup-escape-text) should give you a valid Pango markup string, with no formatting.

Comment: I used Pango in Perl. XML encoded strings can crash Pango. I.e. with character ’ which HTML::Entities encodes to &acirc;&#128;&#153; Even when numerical encoded &#xE2;&#x80;&#x99;
When I used Glib::Markup::escape_text it worked perfectly. Thnx!